# canno't read xml attribute using jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

i have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100" xmlns:rsm="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ram:IssueDateTime>
    <udt:DateTimeString format="102">20230101</udt:DateTimeString>
</ram:IssueDateTime>
</rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice>
```

i created the CrossIndustryInvoice class :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement(name = "CrossIndustryInvoice", namespace = NamespaceMapper.RSM_URI)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CrossIndustryInvoice {
    @XmlElement(name = "IssueDateTime", namespace = NamespaceMapper.RAM_URI)
    private IssueDateTime issueDateTime;

    public IssueDateTime getIssueDateTime() {
        return issueDateTime;
    }

    public void setIssueDateTime(IssueDateTime issueDateTime) {
        this.issueDateTime = issueDateTime;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CrossIndustryInvoice{" +
                "issueDateTime=" + issueDateTime +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and the IssueDateTime

```
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;


@XmlRootElement(name = "IssueDateTime", namespace = NamespaceMapper.RAM_URI)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IssueDateTime {

   

    @XmlElement(name = "DateTimeString", namespace = NamespaceMapper.UDT_URI)
    private String dateTimeString;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "format")
    private String format;

    public String getDateTimeString() {
        return dateTimeString;
    }

    public void setDateTimeString(String dateTimeString) {
        this.dateTimeString = dateTimeString;
    }

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "IssueDateTime{" +
                "dateTimeString='" + dateTimeString + '\'' +
                ", format='" + format + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

when i tried to unmarshal the format attribute is always null.
i've tried to change the @XmlAttribute over the setter and getter method but it generate the following exception :

com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
The class has two properties of the same name ("format")
the maven dependency is the following :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: If your Maven dependency is using the newer **Jakarta** JAXB library, then your code cannot use the older **javax** classes. Your code should not even compile. I would expect to see `jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*` and not `javax.xml.bind.annotation.*`. (Also, what is `NamespaceMapper`?). Can you provide a [mre] which can easily be copied and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using recent `jakarta` libraries (as opposed to the older `javax` libraries):

In the POM, I use these dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

To access both the `DateTimeString` element value and the `format` attribute value, you need an additional class to model the XML nested structure.

Class `DateTimeString`:

```java
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "DateTimeString")
public class DateTimeString {

    @XmlValue
    protected int value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "format")
    protected Byte format;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Byte getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(Byte value) {
        this.format = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DateTimeString{"
                + "format=" + format + " value=" + value
                + '}';
    }

}
```

The above code shows what I referred to in my comments in the question: the change from `javax` to `jakarta` for all the import statements.

(You may want to improve my `toString` format.)

To use this new class, I also changed the `IssueDateTime` class to refer to this class - so, for example, I changed this:

```
private String dateTimeString;
```

to this:

```
private DateTimeString dateTimeString;
```

...and so on.

---

Unmarshalling code:

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CrossIndustryInvoice.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
File xml = new File("CrossIndustryInvoice.xml");

CrossIndustryInvoice cii = (CrossIndustryInvoice) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
System.out.println(cii);
```

My output from my modified `toString` methods:

```
CrossIndustryInvoice{issueDateTime=IssueDateTime{dateTimeString=DateTimeString{format=102 value=20230101}}}
```

---

**Background**

If you are not familiar with the `javax` migration to `jakarta` situation, see here for an overview: [Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee)